# Excel - Comparing Strings within Two Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[NEW IMAGE Updated - CLICK ME!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFbNZ.png)

I am comparing two corresponding columns of data in excel. This is just my example simplified. In the first row, it passes because A and B are in column 2. It does not have to contain C, but it can only be any of the letters contained in cell 1:1. For row three, it does not pass because A is not an option within cell 3:1. What conditional formatting would I do for a large data set

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Conditional formatting rule for `A1:B3`:

```
=ISERROR(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(" "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($B1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&" "," "&$A1&" ")))
```

But since conditional formatting is volatile I don't know if it's wiser to use conditional formatting or just apply the formula to a 3rd column if you are using it on a large dataset. Up to you.

Comment: grrrrr.  beat me by seconds.

Comment: @ScottCraner, let me know what you came up with =)

Comment: my formula is roughly the same but used AND() and OR() : `=AND(OR(ISERROR(SEARCH(" "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($B1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&" "," "&$A1&" "))),$A1<>"")`

Comment: I may have oversimplified the way I asked the question. I am working on classified work and these letters actually represent codes that are not just single characters. I will give you a better example of what these codes look like.

Comment: I added a better example of what I am looking for.

Comment: The same answer can be used. Just use newline characters instead of all the spaces.

Comment: Oddly enough, this function works perfectly in Excel 2016. My classified computer has Excel 2013, and it does not work correctly. Do you have any suggestions on how to make this work for Excel 2013?

Comment: So, after looking at this further, I have discovered that the issue with this formula is that it will return a wrong answer if the order is off. Say the cell B2 contains A2 BB1 B2 CC1 and cell A2 contain B2 CC1 A2 BB1. While they have the same contents, the order is swapped and the formula you wrote returns that they do not match. Could you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

As you might need to run through all entries within one cell, I'm afraid that you might need VBA for solving this one. It would mean that you write an UDF (User-Defined Function) for doing the checking and use that as a basis for a formula for your conditional formatting.

Your function should be something like (not tested):

```
Function chars_inside_string(characters, inside_string) As Boolean
Dim present As Boolean
present = True
test = Split(characters, "-")
For i = 1 To UBound(test)
  present = present AND (InStr(test(i), inside_string) > 0)
Next i
chars_inside_string = present
End Function
```

Comment: I think you want `And` not `Or`.  With `Or` all three cases on their data would return `True` as with `Or` any `True` returns `True` for the whole.  Then you would return: `chars_inside_string = not present`

Comment: @ScottCraner: you're right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.